# Touchpad problem in Gnome shell

Tags: 11.10

For some time the touchpad jerky and I can not understand why. If I log with Unity or create another account (and I log it with "gnome shell") behaves perfectly. You know give me some advice on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Try renaming some of your configuration folders. For example, rename .config to .config-backup and then reboot. See if that helps. You can get your settings back if it doesn't by deleting the new .config folder and renaming the old one back to the original name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it has been very useful. I've replace only the dconf file and now the mouse works very well. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this just so you can mark this as solved ;)

Try renaming some of your configuration folders. For example, rename .config to .config-backup and then reboot. See if that helps. You can get your settings back if it doesn't by deleting the new .config folder and renaming the old one back to the original name.